# event EventHandler is assigned to empty delegate

Tags: c#

I am reading through some code and found this line:

`public event EventHandler Lock = delegate { }`

What does it do?
Why would someone use such a piece of code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually you do:

```
var handler = Lock;
if (handler != null)
    handler(this, args);
```

Using an empty delegate it's never null, so you can just raise `Lock(this, args);`.

Answer (score 2):

There will be a small performance cost for an empty delegate usage, but you use it in order to avoid performing null test. I think it does worth using it. Moreover it's easier to read code:)